# How can I download all Office OneNote 2010 templates from Microsoft site?

Tags: templates, microsoft-office-2010, microsoft-onenote-2010

In http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/templates/CT101527321033.aspx?av=ZSC&ver=14&app=onenote.exe we can find all templates of OneNote 2010 ..

I search for way that allow me download & install all these templates at one time without do that for ever item separately?